# Accessing Computed Properties in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue component and I am trying to set the image src. The data is coming from my api.

```
const product = computed(() => {
    return store.products.find(product => product.slug === route.params.slug);
});

const selectedImage = ref(null);

function setMainImage(image) {
    selectedImage.value = image.original_url;
}

onMounted( () => {
    selectedImage.value = product.default_image;
});
```

The data is in Vue dev tools:

```
product:Object (Computed)
    default_image:"http://localhost/storage/1/photo-1600210492493-0946911123ea.jpeg"
    description:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit ..."
    id:1
```

But the image isn't appearing in my component:

```
<img v-bind:src="selectedImage">
```

Can anyone tell me why this might be happening?

**EDIT**

Here is the cart store:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import { useStorage } from '@vueuse/core';

export const useCartStore = defineStore({
    id: 'cart',
    state: () => ({
        cart: useStorage('cart', { products: [], packages: [] }),
        order: {},
        customer: {},
        loading: true,
        error: null,
        categories: [],
        products: [],
        packages: [],
    }),
    actions: {
        async getProducts() {
            try {
                this.loading = true;

                const resProduct = await axios.get("/api/product");
                this.products = resProduct.data.data;

                const resPackage = await axios.get("/api/package");
                this.packages = resPackage.data.data;

                this.loading = false;
            } catch (error) {
                this.error = error;
            }
        },
...
```

Comment: You've included the `setMainImage` function, perhaps it's being executed, so, what is `image.original_url`

Comment: This is for when a user clicks on another image to display in place of the default

Comment: so if you `console.log(product.default_image)` in `onMounted` it shows `"http://localhost/storage/1/photo-1600210492493-0946911123ea.jpeg"`

Comment: No, it's undefined

Comment: there's your first hint at what could be wrong ... perhaps `store.products` is populated asynchronously - not that you've indicated that one way or another

Comment: Sorry if the question wasn't worded well, I have updated the question with the cart store.

Comment: nah, all good, that's why I made the comment, to find out what's really going on

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

This is how I solved the issue. I removed the onMounted function and updated the product computed call:

```
const product = computed(() => {
    const product = store.products.find(product => product.slug === route.params.slug);
    if (product !== undefined) {
        selectedImage.value = product.default_image;
    }
    return product;
});

const selectedImage = ref(null);
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess it`s a lifecycle issue .. why not you try the following approach :

```
<template>
<div>
    <!-- Display the image once it's loaded -->
    <img v-if="selectedImage" :src="selectedImage" alt="Product Image" />
    <!-- Display a loading message or placeholder image while loading -->
    <div v-else>Loading...</div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import { computed, onMounted, ref } from 'vue';
import { useStore } from 'your-store-module'; // Import your store module

export default {
name: 'ProductDetails',
setup(props, context) {
    const store = useStore(); // Use your store module here
    const product = computed(() => {
    return store.state.products.find(product => product.slug === route.params.slug);
    });
    const selectedImage = ref(null);

    function setMainImage(image) {
    selectedImage.value = image.original_url;
    }

    onMounted(async () => {
    // Assuming you fetch the default image from the API
    // You should await the API call if required
    selectedImage.value = product.value.default_image;
    });

    return {
    selectedImage
    };
}
};
</script>
```

Comment: why is `onMounted` async for no particular reason?

Comment: cause if you fetch from api you will pass await to it ... that`s it

Comment: where's the fetch in the question? where's the fetch in the answer?

Comment: If the value is coming from the computed property, how can I tell vue to wait for the the value to be available?

Answer (score -1):

I think you may need to change the product.value in onMounted.

```
onMounted(async () => {
    await product.value;
    selectedImage.value = product.value.default_image;
});
```

Comment: if `product.value` is a Promise, then `product.value.default_image` won't be anything